# React Unique Key Warning Displayed After Uniqueness Established

Tags: reactjs

So I am learning React. I am using React in a Django project. My first goal is to just list out Blog titles exposed by a blog API from Django. It first fetches the data and the render method uses the map function to list out the Blog titles. As you see below I have a unique key that uses the primary key (pk) value of each blog. This number is inherently unique as established by the Django model.

./components/BlogShow.js

```
import React from 'react'

class BlogShow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       error: null,
       isLoaded: false,
        blogs:null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogs/")
      .then(res => {
          if (!res.ok) {
            throw Error(res.statusText);
        }
        else{
              return res.json()
          }
      })
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            blogs: result
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
        }
      )
  }

  render() {
    const { error, isLoaded, blogs } = this.state;
    if (error) {
      return <div>Error: {error.message}</div>;
    } else if (!isLoaded) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    } else {
      return (
            <div>
                {blogs.map((blog,index) => {
                    return <p><a href="#" key={blog.pk}>{blog.title}</a></p>
                })}
            </div>

      );
    }
  }
}

export default BlogShow
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import BlogShow from './components/BlogShow'

ReactDOM.render(<BlogShow/>, document.getElementById('react'));
```

The problem is I keep getting a warning about unique keys.

> Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"
>   prop.
>
> Check the render method of `BlogShow`.
>       in p (created by BlogShow)
>       in BlogShow

even though the actual React components rendered look like

```
<BlogShow>
    <div>
        <p>
            <a key="1" href="#">Test1</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a key="2" href="#">Test2</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a key="3" href="#">Test3</a>
        </p>
         <p>
            <a key="4" href="#">Test4</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</BlogShow>
```

I know there are other questions about unique keys. I have read through them and tried various things but nothing has stopped this warning. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a map you need a `unique key` on the wrapper and not on the `children`. Check the below snippet

```
 {blogs.map((blog,index) => {
       return <p key={blog.pk}><a href="#" >{blog.title}</a></p>
 })}
```

Comment: I feel like a moron. Thank you. Good to go